# schema JSON produces error "Unparsable structured data" in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, json-ld

From [this article](https://help.woorank.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000136385-Why-can-t-you-find-my-social-media-pages-), I'm using:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "name" : "Motorfix Wangara",
  "url" : "https://www.motorfix.com.au",
  "sameAs" : [
    https://foursquare.com/v/motorfix-automotive-service--repairs/5d7846cccda09f0008a51af7,
    https://www.facebook.com/motorfixperth/,
    https://www.yelp.com.au/biz/motorfix-automotive-service-and-repair-wangara?dsid=ad033,
    https://www.instagram.com/motorfix_perth/,
    https://www.whitepages.com.au/motorfix-automotive-service-repairs-12314283/12314282B,
   ],
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "Unit 2 44 Prindiville Drive, Wangara",
    "addressRegion": "WA",
    "postalCode": "6065",
    "addressCountry": "AU"
  }
}
</script>
```

@ https://www.motorfix.com.au.

However, in Google Search Console, I see an error:

> Unparsable structured data: Incorrect value type

[image]

@ the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.motorfix.com.au%2F) I see

> Syntax error: value, object or array expected.

An array is there.

Can you please tell me how I resolve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add speech marks (") around the URL's you have in that list. Your last URL in the list also can't have a comma after it. I have placed the corrected code below.

```
{
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "Motorfix Wangara",
    "url" : "https://www.motorfix.com.au",
    "sameAs" : [
        "https://foursquare.com/v/motorfix-automotive-service--repairs/5d7846cccda09f0008a51af7",
        "https://www.facebook.com/motorfixperth/",
        "https://www.yelp.com.au/biz/motorfix-automotive-service-and-repair-wangara?dsid=ad033",
        "https://www.instagram.com/motorfix_perth/",
        "https://www.whitepages.com.au/motorfix-automotive-service-repairs-12314283/12314282B"
    ],
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "Unit 2 44 Prindiville Drive, Wangara",
        "addressRegion": "WA",
        "postalCode": "6065",
        "addressCountry": "AU"
      }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!